# Get user's phone number from google people api?

Tags: google-people-api

Can I get the phone number of a user using People API? If not is there any other API that I can use to get a user's phone number? I can't seem to find a anything on that.

below code is what I've tried
First I signIn using auth2.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("window: ", window);
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", initClient);
}, []);

const initClient = () => {
   window.gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: "CLIENT_ID",
   });
   authenticate().then(loadClient);
};

  const authenticate = () => {
    return window.gapi.auth2
      .getAuthInstance()
      .signIn({
        scope:
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log("sign in successful: ", response);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("error signing in: ", err);
        }
      );
  };
```

Then I load the client using.

```
  const loadClient = () => {
    window.gapi.client.setApiKey("API_KEY");
    return window.gapi.client
      .load("https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1")
      .then(
        () => {
          console.log("GAPI client loaded for api");
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("error loading GAPI client for api: ", err);
        }
      );
  };
```

Finally I execute this request to people api to get the info.
I can get the name and email address of the logged in user but I am not getting phone number.

```
  const execute = () => {
    return window.gapi.client.people.people
      .get({
        resourceName: "people/me",
        personFields: "names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers",
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log("people response: ", response);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("people err: ", err);
        }
      );
  };
```

Comment: Are you using a specific programming language, or the REST api? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am building a website with react. I 've tried using People API but wasn't able to get user's phone number.

Comment: Maybe add a code sample where you use the api and expect the contact/person info. Showing the code where you build the people service, as well as the scopes used, would also be helpful.

Comment: Also, don't forget to read the People API doc (https://developers.google.com/people) and perhaps the JavaScript client library for the people API, if that is what you are using (https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md)

Comment: I have edited my question with what I have done to get the phone number. I can get the name and email address using people/me end point but not getting phone number. I have added phone numbers read scope. On the docs it is listed 'phoneNumbers' as a possible value for personFields but I don't why it's not working...

Comment: Just to make sure, you are certain that the target user has a phone number? Is it an account you created for testing purposes? You could also try to access the user using the people.get page (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) just to see if it returns a different result.

Comment: yes I 've created an account for testing purpose and it has a phone number..

Comment: I've also tried from the page directly and the result is the same. no phone number is being returned.

Comment: Does the phone number appear in https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/profile?

Answer (score 3):

You will need the user.phonenumbers scope. From the [OAuth 2.0 Scopes section](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#people):

View your/current user phone numbers

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read
```

You can then use `people.get("people/me")` with `personFields="phoneNumbers"` to get a `Person` instance with the `phoneNumbers` field populated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason for this issue is that the phone number is added to the google account as a "contact number". I was having the same issue and found a link to view the phone number [here](https://myaccount.google.com/profile/phone/edit?index=0). This is the phone number that you were attempting to fetch and you may find that it is empty because google populates "contact number" when you register, and the "contact number" is the phone number on the main google account page.

I am not entirely sure on how to fetch that "contact number" but that is where I believe the issue is.

Feel free to compare the two different pages here:

https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/profile/phone/edit?index=0&pageId=none (this is the one the api you used is able to access)

https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/phone